# Pytest not raising an exception

Tags: python, pytest

I have the following code

```
@blueprint.post("/bulk")
@validate()
def bulk(body: BulkRequestBody) -> tuple[BulkResponseBody, int]:
    try:
        bulk_insert(body.items) # Should raise the exception here.
        return BulkResponseBody(ok=True), 200
    except:  # noqa
        pass

    return BulkResponseBody(ok=False), 500
```

And I have this test for that (other tests works fine):

```
def test_bulk_500(mocker, client):
    # Not sure why the exception is not being raised.
    mocker.patch("app.usecase.bulk.bulk_insert", side_effect=Exception) # Should raise the exception, right?

    response = client.post(
        "/v1/bulk",
        json={
            "items": [
                {
                    "title": "title",
                    "uri": "uri",
                    "date": "2021-01-01",
                }
            ]
        },
    )

    assert response.status_code == 500 # Fails, because status_code is 200.
    assert response.json == {"ok": False}
```

I tried many other forms, no way to make Pytest to raise an Exception when `bulk_insert` is called.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide the code where you define/import `bulk_insert`. I.e. [mre]

Comment: It is located under `app/usecase/bulk.py`, this is correct because if I change to something else, I got and error.

Comment: Is your first code snippet from `app/usecase/bulk.py`, or is it some other module that does `from app.usecase.bulk import bulk_insert` ?

Comment: Ah, got it! But changing to `app.blueprints.v1.project.bulk_insert` does not work either.

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve] -- python code we could run locally to reproduce the behavior you're asking about. Is your application written using flask? Your use of `blueprint` suggests yes, but your use of typed parameters suggests FastAPI.

Answer (score 1):

I think without a complete reproducer we're not going to be able to authoritatively answer your question. This is as close as I could come to a reproducible example, and it works as expected; the test passes.

Here's the server code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from flask import Blueprint, Flask, request, jsonify

blueprint = Blueprint("bulk", "bulk")


@dataclass
class Item:
    title: str
    uri: str
    date: str


@dataclass
class BulkRequestBody:
    items: list[Item]


@dataclass
class BulkResponseBody:
    ok: bool = False


def bulk_insert(items):
    pass


@blueprint.post("/bulk")
def bulk() -> tuple[BulkResponseBody, int]:
    body = request.json
    try:
        bulk_insert(body.items)  # Should raise the exception here.
        return jsonify(asdict(BulkResponseBody(ok=True))), 200
    except:  # noqa
        pass

    return jsonify(asdict(BulkResponseBody(ok=False))), 500


def create_app():
    app = Flask("example")
    app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
    return app


app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And here's the test code:

```
import pytest
import server


@pytest.fixture()
def app():
    app = server.create_app()
    yield app


@pytest.fixture()
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()


def test_bulk_500(mocker, client):
    mocker.patch(
        "server.bulk_insert", side_effect=Exception
    )

    response = client.post(
        "/bulk",
        json={
            "items": [
                {
                    "title": "title",
                    "uri": "uri",
                    "date": "2021-01-01",
                }
            ]
        },
    )

    assert response.status_code == 500  # Fails, because status_code is 200.
    assert response.json == {"ok": False}
```

Running `pytest -v` produces:

```
======================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.7, pytest-7.4.4, pluggy-1.3.0 -- /home/lkellogg/tmp/python/.venv/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/lkellogg/tmp/python
plugins: anyio-4.2.0, mock-3.12.0
collected 1 item

test_server.py::test_bulk_500 PASSED                                                                                                                                                                                                          [100%]

======================================================================
```

Comment: You are right. The problem was the suffix on the package. Changing from `"app.usecase.bulk.bulk_insert"` to `"usecase.bulk.bulk_insert"` solved my issue.